# Problem in google chrome with align-items: center

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling with flex align-items: center. Please see the images for ref. I tried to apply `-webkit-align-items` but this is now the standard property for all the browser as I was reading on the MDN. It never happened to me before the whole development career. Thanks

Mozzila-firefox :

[image]

Chrome + Safari

[image]

```css
div.home {
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  display: flex;
  height: 53px;
  width: 53px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /*-webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  -o-align-items: center;*/
  margin-right: 25px;
}

.element-2 {
  box-shadow: 
    5px 5px 10px 0 rgb(188, 188, 188, 0.45),
    -5px -5px 12px 0 rgb(255, 255, 255, 100);
}

.fa-bell {
  color: #5281C2;
  font-size: 23px !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="home element-2">
    <i class="fa fa-bell"></i>
</div>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/90e4bc8c6b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: I've try your code into chrome and for me works

Comment: hm that's strange

Comment: i've use [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2saox1bz/) with your code on chrome try it.

Comment: I just feel and can see they're not centered as on mozila you know

Comment: I believe you can see the difference

Comment: I don't see any difference in the fiddle.... they are the same... (for me)

Comment: I mean the difference from the pictures above

Answer (score 0):

Try reseting the css using some reset.css like this https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/